# Shallow rendering using enzyme simple test not working

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I am very new to the enzyme/shallow render testing. I probably don't fully understand it yet.

Using this simplified component:

```
export const PlacementOption = (props) => <div/>
const UpdatingSelectField = (props) => <div/>

export class DevicePlatforms extends Component{                                                                                                         
  render(){                                                                                                                                             
    return <div>                                                                                                                                        
      <UpdatingSelectField/>
      {this.props.value.device_platforms && this.props.children}                                                                                        
    </div>                                                                                                                                              
  }                                                                                                                                                     
}
```

I am trying to tests **DevicePlatforms**. If **this.props.value.device_platforms** is not present children are not rendered and if it is they are rendered.

```
import React from 'react';                                                                                                                              
import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';                                                                                                        
import { DevicePlatforms } from './Placement.js';                                                                                                       
import { PlacementOption } from './Placement.js'                                                                                                        

describe("<DevicePlatforms/>", function() {                                                                                                             
  it("with all devices selected renders all children", function() {                                                                                     
    const value = {                                                                                                                                     
      device_platforms: "mobile/desktop",                                                                                                               
    }                                                                                                                                                   
    const Component = <DevicePlatforms                                                                                                                  
      value={value}
    >                                                                                                                                                   
      <PlacementOption/>                                                                                                                                
      <PlacementOption/>                                                                                                                                
    </DevicePlatforms>                                                                                                                                  

    const wrapper = shallow(Component)                                                                                                                  
    expect(wrapper.find('PlacementOption')).toBe(2)
  })                                                                                                                                                    

  it("with no devices selected renders no children", function() {                                                                                       
    const value = {}                                                                                                                                    
    const Component = <DevicePlatforms                                                                                                                  
      value={value}                                                                                                                                     
    >                                                                                                                                                   
      <PlacementOption/>                                                                                                                                
      <PlacementOption/>                                                                                                                                
    </DevicePlatforms>                                                                                                                                  

    const wrapper = shallow(Component)                                                                                                                  
    expect(wrapper.find('PlacementOption')).toBe(0)                                                                                                     
  })                                                                                                                                                    
})
```

I have tried **'PlacementOption'**, **PlacementOption** in a find call.

All I get is a:

```
Expected ShallowWrapper({ many many lines of shallow wrapper content }) to be 3
Expected ShallowWrapper({ many many lines of shallow wrapper content }) to be 0
```

errors.

I can paste the "many many lines of shallow wrapper content" if needed but i don't think it is related and my problem is somewhere else - probably around somewhere around me not knowing how to use shallow render stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're asserting that an enzyme `ShallowWrapper` is equal to 3 or 0. This doesn't make sense.

Instead, the `ShallowWrapper` that is returned from `.find()` has a `.length` property. Try using that instead.

```
expect(wrapper.find('PlacementOption').length).toBe(2)
```

Comment: > This doesn't make sense. Now I know:)